# Android ADB delete /data/data but keep files in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<app name>

Tags: adb

I am inquiring on if it is possible to Re-Install a apk using adb and either before launching or while installing delete the files in `/data/data` but keep the files stored in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data`

Edit:
some context
there is this app for the oculus quest called `QuestCraft` which is VR minecraft standalone on the quest. the script I am writing is to fix a bug where after restarting a `.so` file is deleted from `/data/data` (which I cant just `adb push`) but I found the file could be replaced by re-installing the app. but by reinstalling with the `-r` flag it wont re-unpack the libraries and if I dont specify `-r` all my worlds and servers are deleted from within minecraft.

Comment: Sorry but your question is a little bit confusing as it unclear why you need a script and what it has to do with a .so file being unpacked or not. I would recommend to edit your question and exactly describe what you are trying to do and why. It seems like the used phone is not rooted, because otherwise you wouldn't have to develop such workarounds.

Comment: Baisically i want to delete `/data/data/<app name>` but keep `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<app name>`. the easy way would probally be to `adb pull` the folder and push it back later after installing. but I just want to make sure there is no way to delete that one folder

Comment: `/data/data` is inaccessible to you unless your phone is rooted. `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/` should be accessible to you, so you could try to simply rename the app specific folder within before uninstalling the app.